# Alter Table Mysql da Error

Tags: mysql

tengo la siguiente consulta para [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) pero al hacerla me da error.

```
ALTER TABLE conexion ADD
panel_web varchar (255),
panel_web1 varchar (255),
panel_web2 varchar (255),
puerto_panel varchar (255);
```

La pregunta es ¿cómo hago para agregar varias columnas mediante la misma consulta? (esa misma me funciona bien en **SQL server 2008 r2** pero en **mySQL** no sirve)

Agradezco el apoyo.

Intenté ésta otra que me dijeron aquí pero no resulta me da error

```
ALTER TABLE conexion ADD
panel_web varchar (255) AFTER 
panel_web1 varchar (255)AFTER 
panel_web2 varchar (255) AFTER 
puerto_panel varchar (255);
```

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'varchar (255)AFTER  panel_web2 varchar (255) AFTER

Comment: que error da ??

Comment: ALTER TABLE con ADD COLUMN necesita un AFTER col_name según la [Sintaxis](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) de Mysql

Comment: el 'AFTER' sino me equivoco es para poner la nueva columna a continuación de otra ya existente, para darle un orden concreto

Comment: has conseguido solucionarlo @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prueba a añadir la sintaxis `ADD COlUM` a cada columna nueva que quieras añadir

```
ALTER TABLE conexion
ADD COLUMN panel_web varchar (255),
ADD COLUMN panel_web1 varchar (255),
ADD COLUMN panel_web2 varchar (255),
ADD COLUMN puerto_panel varchar (255);
```

aquí tienes la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) oficial para hacer `ALTER TABLE` de [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Una base de datos almacena sus datos en tablas.

Una tabla es una estructura de datos que organiza los datos en columnas y filas; cada columna es un campo (o atributo) y cada fila, un registro. La intersección de una columna con una fila, contiene un dato específico, un solo valor.

Cada registro contiene un dato por cada columna de la tabla.

Cada campo (columna) debe tener un nombre. El nombre del campo hace referencia a la información que almacenará.

Cada campo (columna) también debe definir el tipo de dato que almacenará.

```
nombre  clave
MarioPerez  Marito
MariaGarcia Mary
DiegoRodriguez  z8080
```

Al crear una tabla debemos resolver qué campos (columnas) tendrá y que tipo de datos almacenarán cada uno de ellos, es decir, su estructura.

La tabla debe ser definida con un nombre que la identifique y con el cual accederemos a ella.

Creamos una tabla llamada "usuarios", tipeamos:

```
create table usuarios (
     nombre varchar(30),
     clave varchar(10)
);
```

Para usar ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE `images` 
ADD `alias` VARCHAR(140) NULL 
AFTER `title`;
```

Y tambien puedes ejecutar varias transacciones con :

```
START TRANSACTION;
TRUNCATE TABLE accounts;
TRUNCATE TABLE accounts_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE accounts_2;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sólo como complemento:

Yo haría los `ADD COLUMN` indicando rigurosamente **cómo quiero que sean mis columnas**, indicando por ejemplo si quiero que acepten o no valores nulos, si quiero que sean `UNSIGNED`, etc. Usar el `AFTER` también es una buena opción, para estar seguro que las columnas se insertarán en el lugar que quiero que se inserten.

Ejemplo:

---

**<kbd>[Demo REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/TGTSR99573)</kbd>**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prueba_add_column
    (`id` int, `nombre` varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO prueba_add_column
    (`id`, `nombre`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Nombre 1'),
    (2, 'Nombre 2')
;

-- Select antes de add column

SELECT * FROM prueba_add_column;

ALTER TABLE prueba_add_column
ADD COLUMN `apellido` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL AFTER `nombre`,
ADD COLUMN `edad` SMALLINT(2) NOT NULL AFTER `apellido`,
ADD COLUMN `status` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AFTER `edad`;

UPDATE prueba_add_column SET `apellido`='Apellido1' WHERE `id`=1;

-- Select después de add column


SELECT * FROM prueba_add_column;
```

**Resultado**

```
-- Select antes de add column

    id  nombre
1   1   Nombre 1
2   2   Nombre 2


-- Select después de add column

    id  nombre      apellido    edad    status
1   1   Nombre 1    Apellido1   0       0
2   2   Nombre 2                0       0
```